# MySQL Join table ON CASE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to `JOIN` a table based on a column value.

SQL I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM user_settings
LEFT JOIN 
    CASE
      WHEN invoice_address = 0 THEN companies
      WHEN invoice_address = 1 THEN users 
    END AS table_to_join
ON table_to_join.id = invoice_id    
WHERE user_settings.user_id = :id
```

At the moment, I use PHP to check if the value equals to something, then execute a second query:

```
if($results['invoice_address'] == "0"){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :id";
}else if($results['invoice_address'] == "1"){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE user_id = :id"
}
```

Comment: OK that's nice. :)